# Validate XML against a DTD external file without DOCTYPE declared

Tags: php, xml, validation, external, dtd

I have external XML and DTD files. The XML file unfortunately doesn't have a  declaration to point to its corresponding DTD file. Is it possible to still validate against it using PHP? Any help or a link to a resource would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Qhat have you tried? Could you show your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate of [XML validation against given DTD in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274173/xml-validation-against-given-dtd-in-php)

```
<?php

$xml = <<<END
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE foo SYSTEM "foo.dtd">
<foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
</foo>
END;

$root = 'foo';

$old = new DOMDocument;
$old->loadXML($xml);

$creator = new DOMImplementation;
$doctype = $creator->createDocumentType($root, null, 'bar.dtd');
$new = $creator->createDocument(null, null, $doctype);
$new->encoding = "utf-8";

$oldNode = $old->getElementsByTagName($root)->item(0);
$newNode = $new->importNode($oldNode, true);
$new->appendChild($newNode);

$new->validate();

?>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, If I had enough rep I'd upvote you. New developer learning and feeling bad that he didn't find it to being with. Have an epic day.