# how can I do DTD and schema validation on a xml file in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xsd, dtd

i have this xml file called data_out.xml, and i want to do DTD and SCHEMA checks on the xml file using SIMPLEXML and php. thank you very much :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplexml won't do it but DomDocument can do it. Also the xml should have some link to the DTD file.

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->Load('book.xml');
if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";
}
?>
```

you can take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101935/validate-xml-using-a-custom-dtd-in-php) for more references

Comment: @getaway: taking a look at this http://www.php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php, it stipulate the extension is enabled by default, so the answer is yes

Comment: how do i create the DTD file, sorry im a newbie

Comment: @getaway: take a look at this website: http://xmlfiles.com/dtd/dtd_intro.asp, I think in your case an external DTD would be the most appropriate